# Стили последних блоков

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый вечер! Делаю рыболовный магазин. На главной, в рекомендуемых товарах, я задал блокам стиль

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
```

Но мне нужно, что бы к двум последним блокам этот стиль не присваивался. Как этого можно добиться? Вот мой магазин - http://fishing-trade.com/ . Вот код рекомендуемых товаров

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-heading"><?php echo $heading_title; ?></div>
  <div class="box-content">
    <div class="box-product">
          <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
          <div>
            <?php if ($product['thumb']) { ?>
            <div class="image"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></a></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="alala">
  <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></a></div>
            <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
            <div class="price">
                  <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
                  <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                  <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
                  <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if ($product['rating']) { ?>
            <div class="rating"><img src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/stars-<?php echo $product['rating']; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $product['reviews']; ?>" /></div>
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="cart"><input type="button" value="<?php echo $button_cart; ?>" onclick="addToCart('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');" class="button" /></div>
  </div>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для массива $product сделать  $product['last_product'] для последних 2 двух позиций со значением 1, для всех остальных 0. И при выводе товаров, проверять если $product['last_product']==1, то применять другой class без нижней границы.

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Хватит в каждом вопросе тыкать ссылку на магазин, уже пара забанить за такой наглый спам.
 в каждом вопросе ссылка на магазин, вы таким образом пытаетесь трафик нагнать?

Comment: Я не думал, что это создает неудобства. Даю ссылку дабы люди имели представление о чем идет речь и легче было подсказать. Трафик я не пытаюсь нагонять, ведь магазина еще нету (я его пару дней только делаю). Извините если создаю проблемы.

Comment: а что в вашем магазине можно увидеть исходный php код? нет.
достаточно указывать точную версию движка.

Comment: Да ладно, ссылку полюбому удобнее смотреть, какой тут спам :)

Answer (score 0):

Мне подсказали сделать так:

Чтобы сходу просто решить проблему, перепишите border-bottom на border-top и уберите этот border-top у первых двух блоков:

```
.box-product > div:first-child,
.box-product > div:first-child + div {
    border-top: 0
    }
```

Это то, что мне было нужно. Всем спасибо

Comment: Да, это более красивый вариант, если это не повредит разметке блоков.